# files not world-readable on CD (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, compact-disc

I got a CD of JPG files from a photographer.  Some of the files are not readable on my Ubuntu machine (they show up as X icons in the Nautilus file browser).  I figured out that the reason is that they are not "world-readable" (and also not "group-readable") and they are owned by a user that does not exist on my machine.  I am able to work around it by doing

```
sudo nautilus
```

Is there any easier way to do this?  I am thinking some setting I can make on my system relating to the CD driver works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing the `norock` option to `mount` will disable Rock Ridge extensions and suppress the permissions recorded on the disc.

Comment: cool... how do I change that in the boot sequence?

Comment: @JoelFan: You don't need to change the boot sequence, simply remount the drive with the `norock` option. Simply look through the first bit of the `mount` manpage. (`man mount`)

Comment: @Hello71, I want it to mount the CD drive like that automatically when it boots.  Otherwise I have to remount it manually each time

Comment: No, you don't. Mount it once, copy the files off it, throw the disc in the circular file, then slap the photographer.

Comment: @Ignacio, do you have any idea how they ended up that way?  Only some of the images, not all!  The photographer uses a Mac in case that sheds any light.

Comment: The program used to burn the disc burned the bogus ownership and permissions as well (`mkisofs` has `-r` to get around this), and since Windows (and maybe OS X, I don't know) doesn't actually *listen* to Rock Ridge, the photographer never knew there was a problem.

Comment: What is the actual command?  I tried "sudo mount /dev/sr0 /media/cdrom0 -o norock" and got: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sr0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error

Comment: I found it elsewhere and put it in as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Here are the commands to mount "norock":

```
me@desktop:~$ mount | grep cdrom  # find out the device and mount point
/dev/sr0 on /media/cdrom0 type udf (ro,nosuid,nodev,utf8,user=me)
me@desktop:~$ sudo umount /media/cdrom0 # unmount the mount point
me@desktop:~$ sudo mount -t iso9660 -o norock /dev/sr0 /media/cdrom0 # mount with "norock"
mount: block device /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
me@desktop:~$
```